# Как пропарсить e926.net в node.js?

Tags: node.js, парсер

Пытаюсь парсить https://e926.net/ чтобы получить картинги с определенным тэгом, но при попытке это сделать выходит ошибка `403`. На их сайте с api (https://e926.net/help/api) написано это:

> If you are using a javascript based method for requests, such as creating a userscript, a browser extension, or are otherwise unable to set a custom header from inside a browser, please attach an additional url query parameter named _client and set it based on how you would have set your user-agent.

Но как сделать запрос с user-agent?
Попытки парсинга проходили по такому запросу: https://e926.net/posts.json?limit=50?tags=hug+order:random

Comment: Просто так ссылка работает, но при парсе через node.js выдает ошибку

Comment: Проблема не решена... Я даже не знаю что делать...